# Issue Resolving dependencies Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**pub get:**

```
Resolving dependencies...
Because fstore depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.0, intl 0.18.0 is required.
So, because fstore depends on intl 0.17.0, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

**If I change the version to 0.18.0 then following are the issue I am facing**

```
Resolving dependencies...
Because every version of charts_flutter from git depends on intl >=0.15.2 <0.18.0 and fstore depends on intl 0.18.0, charts_flutter from git is forbidden.
So, because fstore depends on charts_flutter from git, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

**pubspec.yaml file as follows:**

```
name: fstore
publish_to: "none"
description: Mobile commerce app by Flutter

version: 1.0.5+8

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  inspireui: 1.1.8

  # Base
  intl: 0.17.0
  crypto: 3.0.2
  path_provider: 2.0.11
  url_launcher: 6.1.5
  localstorage: 4.0.0+1
  http: 0.13.5
  http_auth: 1.0.1
  share: 2.0.4
  tuple: 2.0.0
  shared_preferences: 2.0.15
  collection: 1.18.0
  quiver: 3.1.0
  async: 2.11.0
  html: 0.15.0
  vector_math: 2.1.4
  path: 1.8.3
  flutter_svg: 1.1.4

  # FIREBASE PACKAGES
  firebase_core: 1.21.1
  firebase_analytics: 9.3.3
  firebase_auth: 3.7.0
  firebase_remote_config: 2.0.16
  firebase_dynamic_links: 4.3.6
  cloud_firestore: 3.4.6

  # Additional Firebase packages. To prevent unexpected upgrade.
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
  firebase_analytics_platform_interface: 3.3.3
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: 6.6.0
  firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface: 0.2.3+11
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 4.1.3
  firebase_remote_config_platform_interface: 1.1.15

  # PUSH NOTIFICATION
  firebase_messaging: 13.0.0
  notification_permissions: 0.6.1
  flutter_local_notifications: 9.9.1
  onesignal_flutter: 3.4.1

  # STATE MANAGEMENT
  provider: 6.0.3
  get_it: 7.2.0

  # SPLASH SCREEN, ONBOARD
  lottie: 1.4.2
  rive: 0.9.1

  # WEB TOOLS
  html_unescape: 2.0.0
  webview_flutter: 3.0.4
  webview_flutter_web: 0.1.0+4
  responsive_builder: 0.4.3

  #    Code commented to resolve dependency issue.
  #  Issue -> So, because fstore depends on flutterwave_standard from git, version solving failed.
  #  flutter_inappwebview: # 5.4.3+7 - fix xcode 14
  #    git: https://github.com/inspireui/flutter_inappwebview

  flutter_inappwebview: 5.4.3+7

  # HTML render
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: 0.8.5+3
  fwfh_svg: 0.7.2
  fwfh_cached_network_image: 0.7.0+2
  fwfh_url_launcher: 0.6.1+3
  fwfh_chewie: 0.7.0+1
  fwfh_webview: 0.6.2+3

  # VIDEO
  youtube_player_iframe: ^3.0.4

  # MAP
  google_maps_flutter: 2.2.0
  geocode: 1.0.2
  location: 4.4.0

  # AUTHENTICATION
  the_apple_sign_in: 1.1.1
  flutter_facebook_auth: 4.4.1
  google_sign_in: 5.4.1
  sms_autofill: 2.2.0

  # PERMISSION
  # Don't upgrade permission_handler to 10+ version. file_picker is not ready for Android 13.
  permission_handler: 9.2.0

  # FILES, IMAGES
  file_picker: 5.0.1
  cached_network_image: 3.2.2
  image: 3.2.0
  transparent_image: 2.0.0
  image_picker: 0.8.5+3
  flutter_native_image: 0.0.6+1
  flutter_cache_manager: 3.3.0
  wechat_assets_picker: 8.0.2
  photo_manager: 2.2.1

  # TOOLS
  google_fonts: 3.0.1
  random_string: 2.3.1
  json_annotation: 4.6.0
  timeago: 3.3.0
  universal_platform: 1.0.0+1
  uuid: 3.0.6
  easy_debounce: 2.0.2+1
  devicelocale: 0.5.5
  visibility_detector: 0.3.3
  rate_my_app: 1.1.3
  flutter_linkify: 5.0.2
  gms_check: 1.0.0
  new_version: 0.3.1
  video_player: 2.4.7
  in_app_update: 3.0.0
  # google_mobile_ads: 2.0.1

  # UI
  flutter_spinkit: 5.1.0
  smooth_page_indicator: 1.0.0+2
  animated_text_kit: 4.2.2
  flash: 2.0.3+3
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.6.2
  pin_code_fields: 7.4.0
  country_code_picker: 2.0.2
  country_pickers: 2.0.0
  dropdown_search: 5.0.2
  intro_slider: 3.0.10
  flutter_zoom_drawer: 3.0.3
  extended_image: 6.3.0
  dotted_decoration: 2.0.0
  awesome_card: 1.1.7
  maps_launcher: 2.0.1
  qr_code_scanner: 1.0.1
  flutter_calendar_carousel: 2.4.0
  sticky_headers: 0.3.0+2
  jumping_dot: ^0.0.4


  ### Native Payment
  razorpay_flutter: 1.3.2
  paytm_allinonesdk: 1.1.8
  flutter_paystack:
    git: https://github.com/inspireui/flutter_paystack
#    Code commented to resolve dependency issue.
#  Issue -> So, because fstore depends on flutterwave_standard from git, version solving failed.
#  flutterwave_standard: # 1.0.4 - fix XCode 14
#    git: https://github.com/inspireui/Flutterwave

  flutterwave_standard: 1.0.4

  #### For Listing App
  carousel_slider: 4.1.1

  #### For Shopify GraphQL
  graphql: 5.1.1

  ### Flutter 3 fix warning
  charts_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/inspireui/charts.git
      path: charts_flutter
  flutter_swiper_null_safety:
    git: https://github.com/inspireui/flutter_swiper_null_safety
  flare_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/inspireui/Flare-Flutter.git
      ref: fd4bcba22aae4c028286e453deeb78f3311e689a
      path: flare_flutter
  pull_to_refresh:
    git: https://github.com/inspireui/flutter_pulltorefresh


  ###---- Some extra featureen is disable by default -----###
  ###  Facebook Ads
  ### Search "Enable Facebook Ads" & uncomment to use  - https://tppr.me/9Pkf9
  # facebook_audience_network: 1.0.0-nullsafety.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: 2.0.1
  flutter_native_splash: 2.2.8

### Enable to use Flutter Test Driver
#  flutter_driver:
#    sdk: flutter
#  test: 1.16.5
#  dependency_validator: ^3.1.2  # pub run dependency_validator

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/app_icon.png"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/config/
    - lib/config/states/
    - lib/config/stories/
    - assets/icons/brands/
    - assets/icons/credit_cards/
    - assets/icons/tabs/
    - assets/icons/payment/
    - assets/icons/logins/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/country/
    - assets/images/favicon/
    - assets/html/
    - google_fonts/

flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
  use_deferred_loading: true
```

**Flutter Doctou Summery is as follows:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc4)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

***If you require any more information let me know in the comments***

Comment: You might look at completely removing your projects dependency of charts_flutter since it is discontinued. Look at why your app was using that plugin. Is there another plugin that could be used in its place?

Comment: I have purchased this code from inspireUI, I look forward with there team and discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

> It's called dependencies conflict means in one package used previous
> version  and in another package used another version of same package,
> but in latest version their are some breaking changes which makes
> conflicts in your dependencies.

To resolve this issue upgrade your **intl** package to latest version.

> intl: ^0.18.1

and remove all packages which are discontinued.

Comment: All other packages have some functions in the application, its not an option I need that packages as well.